# Go AST: get *struct type

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a code:

```
type someStruct struct {
    Var1 someType `someTags`
    Var2 someType `someTags`
}
//...
test.doSomething(&someStruct{})
```

I am trying to parse it in ast, assume I have:

```
switch t := x.Args[0].(type) {
   case *ast.BaseLit:
      fmt.Println("basic literal"+x.Value)
   case *ast.Ident:
      fmt.Println("Argument identifier":+x.Name)
   default:
      fmt.Println(t) //doesn't print someStruct or *someStruct
}
```

This switch statement is not able to match it (it goes into `default`). How can I proceed?

Comment: That's a composite (not basic) literal and, if I'm not mistaken, it's in a unary expression. The `go/ast` package has representations for both. To confirm it's exact `go/ast` type you can use `fmt.Printf("%T\n", t)` in the `default` case.

Comment: Yes, found it is `*ast.UnaryExpr`. Can you tell me if `t` is `*ast.UnaryExpr` how can I get it is of `*someStruct` type ? doSomething function here takes interface{} as an argument, so I want to determine here the type.

Comment: Get the X of UnaryExpr; assert it to CompositeLit; get its Type expression; assert that to Ident; get its Name... that will produce the *string* `"someStruct"`. And you can prefix it with `*` to get the *string* `"*someStruct"`.